# How to configure DiffUtils 3 in MediaWiki?

Tags: windows, diff, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I started installing [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org) and it needs [DiffUtils 3](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/), but I can not find it to install. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: You didn't even specify your platform.

Comment: Sorry! Windows 8.1, PHP 7.0.5, Apache 2.0, MediaWiki 1.29